In AngularJS, changing the UIB tabset index is only working once
I have a setup similar to the following:
<uib-tabset active="addressTab">
    <uib-tab heading="Search" index="0">
        < ... >
        <button type="button" ng-click="selectAddress()">
    <uib-tab heading="Details" index="1">
        < ... >

The "SelectAddress()" function is simply setting the value of "addressTab".
$scope.selectAddress = function(){
    $scope.addressTab = 1;
}

The first time the button is clicked, this works great, and the second tab is displayed.
However, any subsequent button presses do nothing.
I can see the code is being hit, and the value of "addressTab" goes to 1 as expected, but the UI does not update.
Edit: The button also doesn't work if I have even looked at the second tab, as soon as the second tab has been visible it breaks. There shouldn't be any script running that would cause this.
I am still fairly new to AngularJS and maintaining a legacy project, so not too well versed in how the UI should react / behave here, or if there's an explicit redraw function.
